# Constraint: 07230001 The value is not an allowed value

Tags: alfresco

I have a content model defined and inside it i have a constraint values with LIST type.

I have a page contains r:propertySheet associated with a node of type "Position" and that type have a property refer to the constraint LIST.

The render of the page is correct, but once i execute a code to setProperties from NodeService, i have the following errors.
A system error happened during the operation: 07230003 Found 1 integrity violations: Invalid property value: Node: workspace://SpacesStore/4c7464b2-2c1b-4346-b3f4-215a3818ac9c Type: {www.ds.alfresco.security.extension.com}position Property: {www.ds.alfresco.security.extension.com}permissions Constraint: 07230002 The value is not an allowed value: [READ SADER, WRITE SADER, READ WARED]

Where My Code is:

```
            if(currentPosition != null && currentPosition.getNodeRef() != null){
                Map<String,Object> properties = currentPosition.getProperties();
                ArrayList<String> permissions = (ArrayList<String>)properties.get(Constants.SecurityModelQNames.PROP_SEC_POSITION_POSITION_PERMISSIONS);
                Map<QName,Serializable> qnameSerializableProperties = NodeUtil.prepareQnameSerializableList(properties);
                for(Map.Entry<QName, Serializable> entry : qnameSerializableProperties.entrySet()){
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+","+entry.getValue());
                }
                getNodeService().setProperties(currentPosition.getNodeRef(), qnameSerializableProperties);
            }
```

What i do to make this code executable?

Comment: Are you sure your constraint works? I mean you said that it renders well, but can you create a content & edit the property through the UI?

Comment: Ok, Thanks Tahir my problem has been solved cause the return type is a list

Comment: @MohammedAmr please answer your own question then, so it appears as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, i read the values from the page and fill them in a list and again set this list in the node as property.